# Cypress How to select same-named elements

Tags: xpath, css-selectors, jquery-selectors, cypress

How can I select same-named selectors as I can select in XPath as you can see here?
I select the first element right here.

```
cy.xpath(`(//div[contains(@class,'dx-scheduler-appointment-collector-content')])[1]`)
```

I select the second element right here.

```
cy.xpath(`(//div[contains(@class,'dx-scheduler-appointment-collector-content')])[2]`)
```

what is the exact match is these XPath methods in jquery or CSS.

I need to find jquery or CSS selectors because some of Cypress methods don't work with Xpath.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With CSS selector you can do this:

```js
cy.get('div[class*="dx-scheduler-appointment-collector-content"]').eq(1)
cy.get('div[class*="dx-scheduler-appointment-collector-content"]').eq(2)
```

Comment: How can I use that .eq() method with cy.contains() ---> cy.contains('locator').eq(1)   is that true?

Comment: Yes you can use it like that as well.